# How to add the sum of a dictionary if condition is true

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, random

I'm working on something similar to blackjack. There are only a few of them just for testing. I randomize two different key's from the dictionary. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to add the total sum of the values based on the condition. I do understand that sum() doesn't work in this case, but I want something similar to get the returns from the for loop `item`, which returns two elements and add them together.
Thank you in advance!

```
import random

numbers = {'9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10}
numbers_list = list(numbers.keys())

pick_one = random.choice(numbers_list)
pick_two = random.choice(numbers_list)

print(pick_one, pick_two)
for items in numbers:
    if pick_one in numbers_list and pick_two in numbers_list:
        if pick_one == items and pick_two == items:
            total = sum(numbers[items])
            print(total)
```

Comment: You've made this much harder than it needs to be.  It's just `numbers[pick_one] + numbers[pick_two]`.

Comment: That's not the point. I want to make it simpler. If I have 10 random numbers. Then I will have to write numbers[x] ten times. I know I can do that and that's why I would like some help to see if I can get it to work with a simple line.

Comment: Then you wouldn't create `pick_one` and `pick_two`.  You would create a list of `picks`, which would make it easy to sum their values.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself make numbered variable names, what you really want is a list.

Comment: What's the point of `if pick_one in numbers_list and pick_two in numbers_list:`? You literally just selected the numbers from the list...

Comment: Adding nonsensical logic and writing loops that just pick out one element for the entire loop is very confusing and totally unnecessary. You totally can use sum if you sit and think about how it works, as Tim's answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

numbers = {'9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10}
numbers_list = list(numbers.keys())

picks = [random.choice(numbers_list) for _ in range(2)]
print(picks)

total = sum(numbers[p] for p in picks)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import choice

numbers = {'9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10}   
total = numbers[choice(list(numbers.keys()))] + numbers[choice(list(numbers.keys()))]  
print(total)
```